# Resolving Generic Interface with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Given the following code, how do I resolve the right SomeInstance in autofac?

```
public class BaseClass {}

public class SubClass1 : BaseClass {}

public class SubClass2 : BaseClass {}

public interface IGenericInterface<T> where T : BaseClass {}

public class SomeInstance1<T> : IGenericInterface<T> where T : SubClass1

public class SomeInstance2<T> : IGenericInterface<T> where T : SubClass2
```

I want to choose SomeInstance1 or 2 based on the type of of the generic on the sub classes.

So for example I have a collection of sub classes (SubClass1, 2....) and while iterating over them I want to choose the right SomeInstance class.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Autofac supports open generics. You can use the following code if generics type is known at compile time:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomeInstance1<>))
  .As(typeof(IGenericInterface<>));              

var container = builder.Build();

var instance1 = container.Resolve<IGenericInterface<SubClass1>>();

Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(SomeInstance1<SubClass1>), instance1);
```

If type parameter is not known until runtime (which is likely your case if you want to iterate through collection of types) then you can build your type using MakeGenericType:

```
        var typeInRuntime = typeof (SubClass1);
        var instance1 = container.Resolve(typeof(IGenericInterface<>).MakeGenericType(typeInRuntime));
```

Answer (score 3):

Correction. You cannot call MakeGenericType from the Container.  I solved the issue of instantiating Generics using the 'TYPE' as the parameter on the Resolve call.  The builder is registered.

```
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (FakeRepository<>)).As(typeof (IRepository<>)).OnActivating(e =>
        {
            var typeToLookup = e.Parameters.FirstOrDefault() as TypedParameter;
            if (typeToLookup != null)
            {
                var respositoryType = typeof (FakeRepository<>);
                Type[] typeArgs = {typeToLookup.Value.GetType()};
                var genericType = respositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
                var genericRepository = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
                e.ReplaceInstance(genericRepository);
            }
        });
```

Then the resolution happens like this, passing a TypedParameter to the Resolve.  In this case I have a list of items (IItem) that are resolved that I want to create a repository for all of the items of that type.

```
        var items = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IItem<string>>>();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var repository = container.Resolve(typeof (IRepository<DataItemBase>), new TypedParameter(item.GetType(), item));
            Assert.IsNotNull(repository);
        }
```

Thanks for your post it helped and I Hope this update helps.

Comment: MakeGenericType called as described in the accepted answer by andrey.tsykunov works for me. From the way you describe it, it sounds like you might have tried to call it on the DI container rather than the type.