# Autofac Conventions for Generic Types

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

Im new to Autofac and finding myself repeating a lot of this....

```
builder.RegisterType<ConcreteService<EntityA>>().As<IService<EntityA>>();
builder.RegisterType<ConcreteService<EntityB>>().As<IService<EntityB>>();
```

`EntityA`, `EntityB`, `EntityC` and so on.. all inherit from `EntityBase`, so i want to instruct Autofac to always use `ConcreteService<x>` when it needs to create an implementation of `IService<x>`  as long as x inherits from `EntityBase`

I am aware that the AssemblyScanner in Autofac may be able to help with this, although i am struggling to find documentation that goes far enough into it.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving Generic Interface with Autofac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189519/resolving-generic-interface-with-autofac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189519/resolving-generic-interface-with-autofac) (stackoverflow) may also answer your question.