# Auto Wiring Repository With Generic Type Parameters in Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I'm wondering if there's a convention-based approach for the registering the following in Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<BatchDocumentRepository>()
    .As<IRepository<BatchDocument, IEnumerable<BatchDocument>, int>>();
builder.RegisterType<BatchRepository>()
    .As<IRepository<Batch, IEnumerable<Batch>, int>>();
builder.RegisterType<DeploymentReleaseRepository>()
    .As<IRepository<DeploymentRelease, IEnumerable<DeploymentRelease>, int>>();
builder.RegisterType<DeploymentRepository>()
    .As<IRepository<Deployment, IEnumerable<Deployment>, int>>();
```

The above works fine, but I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner and less repetitive way of doing it. I had a look at this post: [Resolving Generic Interface with Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189519/resolving-generic-interface-with-autofac), but it's not quite the same scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `.As<...>()` with `.AsImplementedInterfaces()`. Beyond that, you could use:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes()
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
                 .Any(i => i.IsGenericType &&
                           i.GetGenericDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>)))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

or something like that.