# Constructor resolve collection of generic interfaces using Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I've got a lot of implementations of a specific generic interface and would like to resolve all of these implementations in the constructor. Of course, I can just add every implementation in the constructor. This will cause the constructor to have over 30 parameters, which isn't very nice to look and develop at.

While doing some research on the matter I discovered it's possible to inject an `IEnumerable` of an interface in the constructor, somewhat like this `IEnumerable<IScriptExecution> scriptExecutionImplementations`

This is what I'm searching for, but I need it to be like so:

```
public TheConstructor(IEnumerable<IScriptExecution<T>> scriptExecutionImplementations)
{}
```

Is it possible to inject all the `IScriptExecution<T>` in the constructor, using Autofac?

The following is an excerpt from my registration class:

```
builder.RegisterType<Library.ShardManager.Execution.DataScript.Users>().As<IScriptExecution<DBUser>>();
builder.RegisterType<Library.ShardManager.Execution.DataScript.Companies>().As<IScriptExecution<DBCompany>>();
```

Note: I don't think I need to use the [Open Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699499/352640), because I already know the types and you can't use open generics in a constructor.

As requested by Jim Bolla in the comment section, an example on how I want to use this.
At the moment I've got this constructor:

```
public MoveShardletData(Guid shardletId, ShardLocation oldLocation, ShardLocation newLocation, ILog log,
            IScriptCreator<DBAnalyticsInvitation> scriptAnalyticsInvitation, IScriptCreator<DBAnalyticsPromotion> scriptAnalyticsPromotion,
            IScriptCreator<DBAnalyticsRetailerSubscriptionModule> scriptAnalyticsRetailerSubscriptionModule, IScriptCreator<DBAnalyticsRetailerSubscription> scriptAnalyticsRetailerSubscription, //and the list goes on...
```

The piece of code where I want to use the `IScriptCreator<T>` objects looks a bit like this:

```
var analyticsInvitations = GetTheAnalyticsInvitationObjects(someLocalVariableInTheCurrentScope)
var script = scriptAnalyticsInvitation.Insert(analyticsInvitations);
sb.Append(script);
//With all IScriptCreator<T> objects listed here in the same fashion.
```

It would be nice if this could be done in a loop. Because of the `someLocalVariableInTheCurrentScope` it's a bit hard to extract this piece of code. 
The collection `analyticsInvitations` is the type `T`. If I can access the Autofac container I can probably resolve the correct `IScriptCreator<T>` manually, but that's cheating thus not advised.

Comment: Managed Extensibility Framework would suit your need much better.

Comment: `IScriptExecution<DBUser>` is a separate type from `IScriptExecution<DBCompany>`, so you would not be able to inject them in a single `IEnumerable<IScriptExecution<T>>` unless you gave them a common interface, perhaps something like `IEnumerable<IScriptExecution>`

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, @Grax. Problem in my case is I need the `<T>` in one of the methods. There's already an interface `IScriptExecution` which contains the methods which don't use the `T`, so I can use the `IEnumerable<IScriptExecution>` solution elsewhere.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you show how you plan on using those objects? Doing so might make it more apparent as to what a solution could be.