# Resolve all derived classes of generic abstract class using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm building a program that will be processing messages from various topics. Since the data on each topic is different, I need dedicated classes that consumes data from any given topic. I want to do so using a base class that handles the communicates with the messaging system, and derived classes that implement the handling of the message:

```
public abstract class MessageConsumer<T>
{
   public void Start(){/*omitted*/}
   /* Other abstract properties and methods here to support template pattern*/       
}
```

The `Start` method will tell the `MessageConsumer` to start pulling in new message. Examples of derived classes are:

```
public class CreatedMessageConsumer : MessageConsumer<CreatedMessage>
{
   /*Implementation omitted*/
}
public class DeletedMessageConsumer : MessageConsumer<DeletedMessage>{}
```

In the code snippet above, I omitted the required constructor arguments, but it's easy to imagine how a DiContainer can be useful here. I use Autofac. The registration of `CreatedMessageConsumer` and `DeletedMessageConsumer` using Autofac works well.

My problem is how to resolve all classes that derives from `MessageConsumer<>`. 
This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189519/resolving-generic-interface-with-autofac) discusses how to resolve a given derived type, but I want to resolve **all** types that derive from `MessageConsumer`. Subsequently I want to call the `Start` method on all of them, e.g. something like

```
foreach(var consumer in container.Resolve<IEnumerable<MessageConsumer<??>>())
{
  consumer.Start();
}
```

However, because I cannot provide the generic argument, it will not compile. Any idea how to do this? I'm using Autofac 4.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not care about the generic argument, (*which you don't otherwise you would have specified a generic argument in your last code block*), then:

- Define an interface (with method Start)
- Implement that on your type(s)
- Add it to the `As` chain where you define your Autofac registrations
- Resolve the new interface

Updated code:

```
public interface IStartable {
    void Start();
}

public abstract class MessageConsumer<T> : IStartable
{
   public void Start(){/*omitted*/}
   /* Other abstract properties and methods here to support template pattern*/       
}
```

Caling code:

```
foreach(var consumer in container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IStartable>>())
{
  consumer.Start();
}
```