# In C# Autofac, how to resolve class from single interface with multiple concrete classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, .net-4.8

I have an interface with multiple classes implementation. I have registered them in Autofac Container. My question how I can resolve for a specific class?

Interface

```
public interface IAccountDataStorage
{
    Account GetAccount(string accountNumber);
    void UpdateAccount(Account account);
}
```

Implemented classes

```
public class BackupAccountDataStore : IAccountDataStorage
{
     ...
}

public class AccountDataStore : IAccountDataStorage
{
     ...
}
```

Register in container

THIS DOES NOT WORK!

```
builder.RegisterType<AccountDataStore>().As<IAccountDataStorage>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<BackupAccountDataStore>().As<IAccountDataStorage>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Now I want to resolve to a specific class

```
// this does not work for me as it will pick itself one of the 
// above class.. need help here
var paymentService = buildContainer.Resolve<IPaymentService>();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving Generic Interface with Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189519/resolving-generic-interface-with-autofac)

Comment: Also, have you read the [Autofac documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) that covers this?

Comment: No, it did not work for me because I need to verify at decide class at resolve

Comment: I have followed this tutorial by register type and resolveTyped and always get the BackupAccountDataStore (2nd one).. https://dotnetfalcon.com/versioning/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer;

```
 builder.RegisterType<AccountDataStore>().Keyed("defaultAccountStorage", typeof(IAccountDataStorage));
 builder.RegisterType<BackupAccountDataStore>().Keyed("backupAccountStorage", typeof(IAccountDataStorage));


var a = buildContainer.ResolveKeyed<IAccountDataStorage>("defaultAccountStorage");
var b = buildContainer.ResolveKeyed<IAccountDataStorage>("backupAccountStorage");
```